# Modifying drop down not working as expected in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, drop-down-menu, prepend

I am having the following code which serves to modify 2 drop down menus on page start and on selection. First one contains main categories which should adapt for the page category which it is one on page load. The second one then offers different options depending on what is selected (either by page start or by selection) in the first.

The following code works perfectly in major modern browsers but NOT as supposed in Firefox.

The problem that occurs that in the first drop down my pageCat option, yes, moves to the top but nevertheless in Firefox the old text is maintained in the visible field. Do I have an semantical problems here?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

// get the page category
var pageCat = jQuery("#page-wrapper .breadcrumb").find("li.active").text().replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();

// get inserted post category instead in case of single seminar
if ( jQuery( ".courses-detail" ).length ) {
    jQuery('.courses-detail').each(function() {
        $courseCat =  this.className.match(/(^|\s)sw_course_cat\S+(\s|$)/);
    } );
    pageCat = $courseCat[0].replace('sw_course_cat-','').trim();
};

// store drop down menus
var $dropDown = jQuery('#page-wrapper select[name="courses[category]"]');
var $dropDown_2 = jQuery('#page-wrapper select[name="courses[location]"]');


// make it the first in the drop down list
// remove “all categories” option
var $standard = $dropDown.find('option[data-link="http://www.falkenberg-seminare.de/cms/edu-course/"]');
$standard.remove();

// change position
var $startList = $dropDown.find('option[value="' + pageCat + '"]');
$startList
    .remove();
$dropDown.prepend( $startList );

// filter the second drop down based on first drop down option selected
var $options = $dropDown_2.clone(); // this will save all initial options in the second dropdown

$dropDown.change( function() {
  var filters = [];
  if ( jQuery(this).val() == "" ) {
    jQuery( this).find("option").each(function(index, option) {
      if ( jQuery(option).val() != "" )
        filters.push(jQuery(option).val());
    });
  } else {
    filters.push(jQuery(this).val())
  }

  $dropDown_2.html("");

  jQuery.each(filters, function(index, value) {
    $options.find("option").each(function(optionIndex, option) { // a second loop that check if the option value starts with the filter value
      if ( jQuery(option).val().startsWith(value) )
        jQuery(option).clone().appendTo( $dropDown_2 );
    } );

  } );
  } );

  $dropDown.trigger('change');

} );
```

I am sorry to not deliver a Fiddle but I cannot imagine how to emulate the pageCat selection to demonstrate correctly on page load. But maybe there is some known Firefox code problem that I do not know about (and Google didn’t help).

Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Extending my code:

```
// same initially on page load
$dropDown
  .trigger('change')

  // add this for Firefox
  .val(pageCat)
  .change();
```

solved my problems. I also added html attribute: autocomplete="off" to my select tags to avoid Firefox caching.
If someone is interested or has the same problem please put a comment and I will add a fiddle.